# Why the div does not take the remaining space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a div structure like this,

```
<div style="height:100%">
    <div style="height:50px"></div>
    <div id="auto" style="height:100%"></div>
</div>
```

But it seems like  `id="auto"` is taking the height as its parent height and the parent overflows. Can just set css in a way that `id=auto` div take the remaining height of the parent ?
What I'm trying to do is to make the `id=auto` div to take the rest of the space on parent div resize.

here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rn2Xe/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because percentage value for `height` property is relative to the height of box's containing block. Therefore `100%` means the entire height.

> **[10.5 Content height: the 'height' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property)**
>
> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with
>   respect to the height of the generated box's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block). If the
>   height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it
>   depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely
>   positioned, the value computes to 'auto'. A percentage height on the
>   [root element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/conform.html#root) is relative to the [initial containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details).

One solution would be using a negative margin for the second `<div>` element to remove the srcollbar and then adding `position: relative;` to the first one to bring it back on the top of the second one.

In this case we should use `padding` on top of the second div to push its content down and also adding [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) in order to calculate the height of the box including padding borders:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/rn2Xe/3/)**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent { height:100%; }

.top {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    background-color: gold;
    min-height: 100%;

    margin-top: -100px; /* equals to the height of .top element */
    padding-top: 100px; /* equals to the height of .top element */

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It's worth noting that this approach [would work on **IE8+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Browser_compatibility).

---

Nowadays all major web browsers support `box-sizing: border-box`, however you use a spacer element instead of `padding`+`box-sizing` to push the content of `.content` down:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/rn2Xe/6/)**.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <!-- content goes here -->.
</div>
```

```css
.spacer, .top {
    height: 100px;
}
```

This approach would work on **IE 6/7+**<sup>(*)</sup>

---

Alternatively, you could nest the `.top` element within the `.content` and drop the `.parent` in order to achieve the same result which is working on **IE 6/7+**<sup>(*)</sup>.

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/rn2Xe/5/)**.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="inner">
        <!-- content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

---

<sub>**(*) IE6+** by using `height` property, **IE7+** by using `min-height`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support IE8 or IE9, use CSS calc (http://caniuse.com/calc)

```
<div style="height:100%">
    <div style="height:50px"></div>
    <div id="auto" style="height:calc(100%-50px);"></div>
</div>
```

If you do need to support the older IE's, then I would suggest using display:table, display:table-cell, and display:table-row.  There are a lot of little quirks to keep in mind when using the table displays, so stick with calc if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result, if you can absolutely position the first child div (the one that is 100 pixels tall):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rn2Xe/2/

```
<div style="height:100%; padding-top:100px; box-sizing: border-box; position: relative;">
    <div style="height:100px; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"></div>
    <div style="height:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Note: Use classes for CSS. Your code could be *much* cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to solve this with css `calc`, but if you want good legacy support, use tables.